# How to check whether an eTag received from a firebase database has changed when using the firebase REST API?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I found ways to conditionally update or write data to the database using eTag. But what I want is to **Read (GET)** the changed data from the database, if the data has changed, using the REST API and **not to update the data**

I am trying to implement a server side cache of the database, and I want to update the cache if it is old (eTag has changed).

Answer (score 2):

Performing conditional updates with the REST API is a multi-step process:

- Whenever you read data from the database, you need to make sure you also request an `ETag` by passing in an `X-Firebase-ETag` header with the value `true`.
- Firebase will then respond with the data and `ETag` header in the response, like `ETag: ViJFJowpbyRvgGNPzPJdGeN+mCY=`
- You need to store the `ETag` in the same place where you store the data.

Now when you want to send a conditional update, you:

- Read the existing `ETag` for that location from your cache.
- Pass the `ETag` in an `if-match` header to the write request with your new data, like this: `-H 'if-match: ViJFJowpbyRvgGNPzPJdGeN+mCY='`

At this point the Firebase Realtime Database server compares your `ETag` value with the `ETag` for the current data. There are two possibilities:

- If the `ETag` values are the same (i.e. if the data was not modified), your write is persisted to storage.
- If the `ETag` values are different (i.e. if the data on the server was updated) your write is rejected, and you get back the updated data and `ETag` in the response. At this point you should write the new data and `ETag` to your cache, and retry the update based on those values.

For more on this see:

- The [blog post introducing the conditional updates](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/07/introducing-conditional-rest-requests.html).
- The [documentation on conditional updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-conditional-requests).

There is no support for passing the `ETag` into a `GET` call. It sounds like a reasonable feature request, so I'd recommend you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). But there's no guarantees on whether/when this will be implemented.

Comment: I do not want to update the data (PUT, POST etc). I just want to know whether the data has changed and READ the changed data using a simple GET request.

Comment: There is no support for passing the `ETag` into a `GET` call. It sounds like a reasonable feature request, so I'd recommend you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). But there's no guarantees on whether/when this will be implemented.